# Using paste.progress In A Pyramid Project

Tags: python, wsgi, paste, middleware, pyramid

I need to keep track of a file's upload progress and found the [paste.progress middleware](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/progress.html). It seems like what I want. How would I add and use the paste.progress middleware in a Pyramid project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File uploads with WSGI middleware were recently [commented](http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/browse_thread/thread/d8e852df520bb213) at Pylons user group.